# Using Socket.IO together with Express and NodeJS exports

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to connect my Express and Socket connection together. I think I have this setup neatly, but not when I want to do this:

1. An user creates a new room. POST to the backend Express server.
2. The `app.post()` then sends the input into an exports, which handles all the database connection.
3. When it's saved in the database, broadcast to everyone via sockets that a new room has been added.

Could this be done solely with sockets? Yes. But I'm not about that life.

**RoomRouter.js**

```
exports.createRoom = (req, response) => {
    new Room(req.body).save((err, room) => {
        response.status(200).send(room);
    });
};
```

**app.js**

```
/*
 * Express setup is left out, because we don't need to focus on that.
 * "app" is const app = express();
 */
const RoomRouter = require("./RoomRouter");

app.post("/room/create", RoomRouter.createRoom);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    //I want to broadcast the room to everyone
    //io.emit("newRoom", room);
});
```

The Express part works fine and the POST works. Now, how do I connect Socket.IO to that, so I can broadcast to everyone that a new room has been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you really want, but if you want to use socket io in your route, I think you have to declare your route like this :

**RoomRouter.js**

```
exports.createRoom = (io) => {
   return (req, response) => {
      new Room(req.body).save((err, room) => {
         io.emit("newRoom", room);
         response.status(200).send(room);
      });
   };
};
```

And in your **app.js**

```
app.post("/room/create", RoomRouter.createRoom(io));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm not quite what I want. `createRoom` already takes `req, response` as parameters.

Comment: Yes, but with this method, you also can take `io` as parameter, and then emit `newRoom` directly in your route :)

Comment: Oh yeah I see that now - Interesting. Instead of parsing `io` to every method, wouldn't it be better to include it somehow instead? Like make a service that can be included everywhere, perhaps?

Comment: Humm.. My method is passing `io` to each routes, but I think you also can do it with differents ways :)